# Issues accessing companyweb on macs

Tags: mac

Currently having problems getting access to the companyweb using Macs. The companyweb is hosted on SBS2008 and any other devices such as ipads and windows machines work no problem.

Users can just type in companyweb and it takes them to http:// companyweb/default.aspx. The server is used as the primary DNS server for the network.

However, on the Macs this does not work. I cannot ping companyweb but I can ping the server. I have found that I can access the secure site by going to https:// serveraddress:Portnumber.

When going to the non-secure site http:// serveraddress:PortNumber I get access is denied.

Does anyone have any ideas what I should try next?

Answer (score 1):

So, I take it that *companyweb* is a Sharepoint site running off the SBS2008 server?

The "Access Denied" error you're seeing may be showing up because HTTP Redirect isn't set up in IIS for the site, but that's a separate, unrelated issue.

I've seen that sometimes Macs have some issues inter-operating with Windows DNS.

A few things to try:

- Open **System Preferences** > **Network** > on the sidebar, select **Wi-Fi** (or **Ethernet**) > click **Advanced** > select the **DNS** tab, look under **DNS Servers**, and check what the Mac is using for DNS.
- Restart the Mac's **mDNSResponder** service: 
  sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
- Open Terminal, and try looking up a public site: 
   
  nslookup www.apple.com **or** dig www.apple.com

9 times out of 10, Apple's mDNSResponder is clashing with the Windows DNS server, and re-starting the mDNSResponder service sets it right.

References: 
[Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5343) 
[DNS not resolving on Mac OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26616/dns-not-resolving-on-mac-os)